# If a web application provides an API in addition to user interface (GUI), then which tier does the API com under

Tags: api, architecture, three-tier

I have developed a web application which has a GUI (Presentation tier), Servlet classes for processing data (Business Logic Layer) and a RDBMS (Data Tier). Now my application also provides an API for some of its functionality, so when i represent the architecture will the API b part of Business logic or Presentation tier?

Comment: It is probably most helpful to consider the API an alternative "presentation" tier. Unless your GUI code uses the same API itself, that is.

Comment: so if it uses the same API then it would come in Application tier?

Comment: Well, if it's the main API you have between the business logic and presentation layers, then that's a pretty unambiguous explanation of what it is, isn't it?

Answer (score 0):

Q: Why must you consider the API a "tier"?

For the sake of argument, let's define a "tiers" as:

> A structuring mechanism for the elements that make up the software
>   solution

If you think about it this way, wouldn't your API cut *across* all three tiers (or at least across all of the tiers you've exposed with your API)?